# how to solve the complete and uncomplete problem if the todolist?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this question has been posted here by someone else before and the problem with the node-children has been solved but i still have a problem when toggling the complete option it removes everything from the page but the uncompleted and all option it shows all list whether they have been checked done or not is not relevant please help me understand and fix the problem

```js
// SELECTING
const myClick = document.querySelector(".myclick");
const myList = document.querySelector(".mylist");
const myInput = document.querySelector(".myinput");
const myFilter = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");


// EVENT LISTENERS
myClick.addEventListener("click", addItem);
myList.addEventListener("click", deleteMe);
myFilter.addEventListener("click", filterOption);




// FUNCTIONS
function addItem(e) {

  //prevent from submiting form (here we dont have form )
  e.preventDefault();

  //creating div to put check and delte btns inside and then putting it inside the myList.
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("newdiv");
  myList.appendChild(newDiv);
  const newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.classList.add("newitem");
  newItem.innerText = myInput.value;
  myInput.value = "";
  newDiv.appendChild(newItem);


  // adding the checked btn
  const checkBtn = document.createElement("button");
  checkBtn.classList.add("check");
  checkBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="lni lni-checkmark"></i>';
  newDiv.appendChild(checkBtn);

  // adding the trash btn
  const trashBtn = document.createElement("button");
  trashBtn.classList.add("trash");
  trashBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="lni lni-trash"></i>';
  newDiv.appendChild(trashBtn);
}

function deleteMe(e) {
  const myTarget = e.target;
  // delete list
  if (myTarget.classList[0] === "trash") {
    const list = myTarget.parentElement;
    // create class to add the remove animation
    list.classList.add("fal");
    // we removed the remove() here because it removed the animation before it took effect
    list.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
      list.remove();
    });

  }
  if (myTarget.classList[0] === "check") {
    const list = myTarget.parentElement;
    list.classList.toggle("complete");
  }
}

function filterOption(e) {
  const todos = [...myList.children];
  todos.forEach(function (todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        }
        else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }

  });

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #d05fda;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #d05fda, #72b1f2);
}
.container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.mybtn {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.myinput,
.myclick {
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  background: cornsilk;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #292626;
}
.myinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.myclick {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #a300ee;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.myclick:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.myclick:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #a300ee;

}
.mylist {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #292626;
}
.newdiv {
  transition: all 0.7s ease;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(240, 214, 228);
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgb(245, 237, 245);
}
/* make the check mark to go to the ned of the div */
.newdiv li {
  flex: 1;
}
.check {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #128812;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.check,
.trash:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.check:hover {
  background: rgb(228, 188, 196);
}
.trash:hover {
  background: rgb(237, 238, 175);
}
.check i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.trash {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #ee5700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.trash i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.fal {
  transform: translateY(100px) rotateZ(25deg);
  opacity: 0;
}


select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
 
}
.select {
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}
select {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #7c05b3;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;

}
.select::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #a300ee;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.select:hover::after {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #a300ee;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="your-project-dir/font-css/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My List</h1>

    

<div class="box">
  <div class="mybtn">
    <input class="myinput" type="text">
    <button class="myclick"><i class="lni lni-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
    <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
      <option value="all">ALL</option>
      <option value="completed">Completed</option>
      <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="mylist">

</ul>
  </div>
  

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// SELECTING
const myClick = document.querySelector(".myclick");
const myList = document.querySelector(".mylist");
const myInput = document.querySelector(".myinput");
const myFilter = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");


// EVENT LISTENERS
myClick.addEventListener("click", addItem);
myList.addEventListener("click", deleteMe);
myFilter.addEventListener("click", filterOption);




// FUNCTIONS
function addItem(e) {

  //prevent from submiting form (here we dont have form )
  e.preventDefault();

  //creating div to put check and delte btns inside and then putting it inside the myList.
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("newdiv");
  myList.appendChild(newDiv);
  const newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.classList.add("newitem");
  newItem.innerText = myInput.value;
  myInput.value = "";
  newDiv.appendChild(newItem);


  // adding the checked btn
  const checkBtn = document.createElement("button");
  checkBtn.classList.add("check");
  checkBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="lni lni-checkmark"></i>';
  newDiv.appendChild(checkBtn);

  // adding the trash btn
  const trashBtn = document.createElement("button");
  trashBtn.classList.add("trash");
  trashBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="lni lni-trash"></i>';
  newDiv.appendChild(trashBtn);
}

function deleteMe(e) {
  const myTarget = e.target;
  // delete list
  if (myTarget.classList[0] === "trash") {
    const list = myTarget.parentElement;
    // create class to add the remove animation
    list.classList.add("fal");
    // we removed the remove() here because it removed the animation before it took effect
    list.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
      list.remove();
    });

  }
  if (myTarget.classList[0] === "check") {
    const list = myTarget.parentElement;
    list.classList.toggle("complete");
  }
}

function filterOption(e) {
  const todos = [...myList.children];
  todos.forEach(function (todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("complete")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        if (!todo.classList.contains("complete")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        }
        else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }

  });

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #d05fda;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #d05fda, #72b1f2);
}
.container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.mybtn {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.myinput,
.myclick {
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  background: cornsilk;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #292626;
}
.myinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.myclick {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #a300ee;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.myclick:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.myclick:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #a300ee;

}
.mylist {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #292626;
}
.newdiv {
  transition: all 0.7s ease;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(240, 214, 228);
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgb(245, 237, 245);
}
/* make the check mark to go to the ned of the div */
.newdiv li {
  flex: 1;
}
.check {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #128812;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.check,
.trash:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.check:hover {
  background: rgb(228, 188, 196);
}
.trash:hover {
  background: rgb(237, 238, 175);
}
.check i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.trash {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #ee5700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.trash i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.fal {
  transform: translateY(100px) rotateZ(25deg);
  opacity: 0;
}


select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
 
}
.select {
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}
select {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #7c05b3;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;

}
.select::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #a300ee;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.select:hover::after {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #a300ee;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="your-project-dir/font-css/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My List</h1>

    

<div class="box">
  <div class="mybtn">
    <input class="myinput" type="text">
    <button class="myclick"><i class="lni lni-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
    <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
      <option value="all">ALL</option>
      <option value="completed">Completed</option>
      <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="mylist">

</ul>
  </div>
  

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you are adding a **complete** class when the user marks a list item as **completed** but in the filters code you are using **completed** class to filter the list.